# WALS Model Tensorflow - Get recommendations for new user

Tags: python, tensorflow, recommendation-engine

I wonder if there is any way I can get recommendations for a new user, using an already trained WALS model, and given the list of items the user liked.

Currently, to get a recommendation you must provide the id of the user, which must be among the users the model was trained with. I would like to get a recommendation by providing the list of items that were liked by a new user.

There is a similar feature in the [implicit](https://github.com/benfred/implicit/pull/35) python library

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is called "cold start problem".

You want a recommendation from no information on user's past behaviour.

As Matrix factorization needs historical data from the user, the best recommendation you can make if a most-popular recommendation.

To tackle this problem, you can add another type of model that handle this. You can, for example, add user's data in the algorithm in order not to be absolutely dependant on past data or by doing the online recommendation by analysing data during session.